# Xcode 12 iOS 14 Widget without SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, widget, ios14, xcode12, widgetkit

Is it possible to create Xcode widget in Xcode 12 but **without** the use of SwiftUI and instead use XIB files to construct the Widget UI?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`Widget` protocol is only available in `SwiftUI` framework, so you can only create widgets using SwiftUI.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/widget

**Update**

You can't use UIKit views wrapped in `UIViewRepresentable` within SwiftUI for Widgets, It will appear blank.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/653471

Comment: According to my tests UIKit views wrapped in UIViewRepresentable will not work in widgets. This answer from an Apple frameworks engineer suggest it as well: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/653471

Answer (score 10):

No, due to performance and battery life concerns, WidgetKit only works with SwiftUI.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit

> You configure the widget with a timeline provider, and use SwiftUI views to display the widget’s content. The timeline provider tells WidgetKit when to update your widget’s content.

Comment: Why would performance/battery life be worse with UIKit?

Comment: Nonsense. Apple just trying to force us to use swiftUI even if we don't want.